# "Invalid encoding for NameConstraintsExtension" when connecting to a web service over SSL

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, truststore, rampart

I've got some SSL problems here with a webservice call. Things seemingly work fine in production with the same setup of certificates in truststore, but when I try to run a certain certificate-signing web service call against the backend (that I have no control over), there is the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid encoding for NameConstraintsExtension.
>       at java.security.cert.TrustAnchor.setNameConstraints(TrustAnchor.java:283)
>       at java.security.cert.TrustAnchor.(TrustAnchor.java:132)
>       at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin.validateCertPath(Merlin.java:157)
>       at org.apache.rampart.PolicyBasedResultsValidator.verifyTrust(PolicyBasedResultsValidator.java:807)
>       at org.apache.rampart.PolicyBasedResultsValidator.validate(PolicyBasedResultsValidator.java:168)
>       at org.apache.rampart.RampartEngine.process(RampartEngine.java:331)
>       at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:92)

Apparently this is not just the case of certificates being trusted; there is some wrong "encoding" there at some point. So being clueless and not knowing where to even start, I'd need some hints as to...

- What is a NameConstraintsExtension
- What kind of encoding might be expected here?

EDIT: It seems like this is not related to anything in the truststore, but actually the keystore, which makes it all the weirder as the same client-side authentication works fine in production. And there are no "NameConstraintExtensions" anywhere in any of the certs that are involved, as far as I can tell.

Comment: See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.10 (et pred). Although NameConstraints was defined in X.509v3 decades ago, in practice I've very rarely heard of anyone using it, and then usually in the form of bug reports because it didn't work.  If you are (or your app/system is) using it intentionally you may be breaking new ground. If you can figure out which cert this code is using, I would look at it by hand to at least determine whether the error is on the create/generate side or the parse/use side.

Comment: Well we certainly are not breaking new ground as NameConstraintExtensions do not show up anywhere in any of the certs...

Comment: Please quote error messages *accurately.*

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same error, and it seems it is not so common, so I couldn't find an answer.  I was using openjdk in linux.  I tried with different versions: 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0.  I thought the error was in the certificate, but finally the solution was to install jdk or jre from Sun /Oracle.
Hope it helps someone.